# Handling ms access lookups in mysql

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, recordset

I'm migrating a system from access to mysql. I have migrated all the tables and data successfully to mysql. But there is a problem in a specific part.

In Access, you can set up lookups for columns. So I have a table named "roles" which has different roles an employee can take. And in the table named "employees", there is is a column named "roles" which has a lookup defined and can take multiple values.

So in effect, an employee can have multiple roles. Now there are no relationship between the two tables, but the roles column (in employees table) feeds from the roles table. So when I migrated to mysql, the roles column was populated with the roles separated by a ";".

The problem comes in the vba code.

```
Dim Rs As Recordset
Dim ChildRs As Recordset
Set Rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("<<the employees table>>")
Rs.MoveFirst
// some more code

Set ChildRs2 = Rs![<<the roles column>>].Value // this returns a recordset
```

Currently, this code works because Rs![the roles column].Value with the access database returns a recordset, and the code continues. Now with mysql, the same statement returns just the value of the field (such as role1;role2;role3).

And the code breaks.

```
// with access database
Rs![<<the roles column>>].Value returns a recordset
Rs![<<the roles column>>].Value.Value returns something like role1;role2;role3

//with mysql
Rs![<<the roles column>>].Value returns the value like role1;role2;role3
```

So you can see the problem. Now currently I'm thinking that I'll modify the vba code, and maybe create a many to many relationship between the two tables.

There maybe some workaround to get this working in mysql which I'm not aware of. So any help would be appreciated. I found this answer but that doesn't address my issue: [Access Lookup in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716578/access-lookup-in-mysql)

Comment: In SQL (mySQL, SQL Server, etc.) you would handle this normally using a many-to-many setup. This require 3 tables -- the two you have and a third "linking" table. Basically, this table has two foreign keys, one to the employees table, and another to the roles table. It may have other columns if needed, but it is used to store the relationship between the employee table and the roles table.

Comment: I never set lookups in table. I build comboboxes and listboxes on form. And multi-value fields don't migrate nicely to other database platforms. Only Access has this structure. I expect you will have to redesign.

Comment: As per @June7 http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm